# Template type transformation needed to store various value classes?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to have a class with a shared_ptr who's value can be accessed through a getter.  Something like this:

```
template <class T>
struct async_result {
    T& value() {
        return *ptr_;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr_;
};
```

Which works fine with regular value classes.  I'll have a specialization for the case T=void, but I'd like to be able to store references and pointers in this as way as well.  What sort of transformations on T do I need to perform to decay types appropriately?

Comment: I see no reason why this template cannot be used with a pointer as a template parameter. As far as using a reference, for a template parameter, that seems somewhat dubious. Perhaps a specialization that uses `std::ref`.

Comment: Seconded.  This should just work, with the caveat that you use a `std::reference_wrapper` for storing references.

Comment: Turns out it does work with pointers.  I'll look at std::reference_wrapper.  Do I need to do anything special for it work with const?

Comment: You shouldn't.  `std::shared_ptr` works when its type is `const`.

Comment: OK, so just specialize for T& and use reference_wrapper in shared_ptr?  What about rvalue-references?

Comment: For pointers, try to use `shared_ptr`, so that it is resolved into `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<your_type>>`, but about references,  as @NathanOliver says, don't. Also don't use raw pointers, it would be dangerous.

Comment: My full implementation is up here in case anyone has thoughts: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205043/async-function-call-implementation